# In Spring Data MongoDB, is there a way to upsert a document when using @Update with a findAnd...ById method?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, upsert

*Note: example is using Spring Data MongoDB in Kotlin leveraging update methods as described at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.update.*

Consider this entity and repository:

```
@Document
data class Foo(
    val name: String,
    val bars: Set<String> = setOf(),
    @Id
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
)

@Repository
interface FooRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Foo, String> {
    suspend fun saveOrAddBarsFrom(foo: Foo) {
        if (findAndAddToSetBarsById(foo.id, foo.bars) == 0) {
            save(foo)
        }
    }

    @Update("{ \$addToSet : { 'bars' : { \$each :  ?1 } } }")
    suspend fun findAndAddToSetBarsById(id: String, bars: Set<String>): Int
}
```

If you notice the method `saveOrAddBarsFrom`, it takes two round trips to upsert the `Foo`:  one trip to attempt to `$addToSet` the given strings to an existing `Foo`, and, if none were updated, one trip to `save` the `Foo` since it wasn't found, effectively providing upsert behavior.

Is there a way to craft a method that, *in one round trip*, `save`s a `Foo` if it doesn't exist or adds the strings to the `bars` collection if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Update` query doesn't take any option to specify whether the document needs to be upserted. This is the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Update.html) to the official documentation.

However, you can try some to upsert documents, like this:

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(MongoClients.create(), "database"));
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(foo.id));
Update update = new Update().addToSet("bars").each(foo.bars);

Foo upserted = template.update(Foo.class)
  .matching(query)
  .apply(update)
  .withOptions(FindAndModifyOptions.options().upsert(true).returnNew(true))
  .findAndModifyValue()
```

You can check it out in the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.find-and-upsert).